# how to retrieve security token from salesforce thru a web-service call..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, salesforce, sts-securitytokenservice

is there any way to send a web-service call to salesforce n get a security token which is reseted in desktop side...

it is possible to do this before login..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this, as that would defeat the entire purpose of the security token.